# How to "cancel" an observable produced by an operator

Tags: angular, webrtc, rxjs

In general terms, I have a single "parent" observable that produces values, and then I have an arbitrary number of "children" observables that produce their own streams of values based on the last given value from the "parent". I need these children observables to be "cancellable" in such a way that they stop producing values, while their siblings proceed merrily along. Any observables created from operations on the child observable should be "cancelled" as well. Cancellation should include freeing up the memory used by the child observable (and it's children).

More specifically, I am using the Web Audio API. The parent observable produces `AnalyserNode`s. The children observables are created by calling `switchMap()` on the `AnalyserNode` observable. The observable returned by the `switchMap` is a new `Observable.interval` that produces fft frames from the `AnalyserNode`.

The idea is to be able to arbitrarily create and destroy `FftFrame` streams that are all fed by the same `AnalyserNode`

```js
    let fftSpec = {interval: 100};
    let fftFrame$ = analyserNode$.switchMap((analyser: AnalyserNode) => {
      let fftFrame = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
      return Observable
        .interval(fftSpec.interval)
        .map(() => {
          analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fftFrame);
          let copy = new UintArray(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
          copy.set(fftFrame);
          return copy;
        });
    });
```

Comment: A stream stops executing when it has no subscribers - have you tried saving the subscriptions and calling `unsubscribe` yet?